# c# webbrowser control printing

Tags: c#, html, printing, webbrowser-control

I'm using the web browser control in an application to display a report. The report is just straight HTML text but is fairly wide. When I preview the print using the `.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()` I see that the report is truncated on the right hand side, even when switched to landscape mode.

Currently I am only calling the `.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()` method and then calling the `.ShowPrintDialog()` method to actually print the report.

My question is ... how do I get the report to print over multiple pages? I'm perfectly fine with spanning the report over X number of pages in landscape mode but I'm not sure what flag to set or how to set the control to actually split the report over multiple pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not let the webbrowser control handle the printing for you. I have successfully done this where a report data was in xml, and applied a xslt transformation to html and used the webbrowser control to display the report and let the user make the choice in printing it. Here is a link to CodeProject on this [webbrowser wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx). There is a method in there to do a print (which includes the print preview as rendered by the control itself).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: @tommieb75: Thanks for the reply! Acutally I am letting the browser handle the printing for me and I think that's what is causing the issue. I'm not sure why but it won't print the entire report over multiple pages. It just stops at a certain point. I'm just using the native print methods within the control.

Comment: @Scott Vercuski: Oh...Now I understand, I am not sure now how would you do this...but have a look here...http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/custom_paper_sizes.aspx,other than that I am stumped..I would imagine that there would be an option via p/invoke to force the print layout over multiple pages. I have not seen IE doing this... :( Sorry if I cannot help you any further..

Comment: @tommieb75: That's ok ! I appreciate the effort ! I'll dig into the printing link and see where that leads me. Thanks again.